# Does immersion actually work?

Tags: immersion

I’ve heard people say constantly that “immersion is great and you’ll learn a language that way”. Some even go as far as saying that immersion is the *only* way to learn a language. But is it really true? After all, you’re just guessing what a word or phrase means. Why do so many people praise immersion? Does it actually work?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Your question is on topic here, but we have a lot of related questions, such as [How can immersion in the language's country improve beginner skills?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/19/800), [How does immersion passively help with learning a language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/13/800), [Studies on average time by full immersion in 2nd+ language to become conversant?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3515/800) ...

Comment: ... and [Does learning a new language while in the target country instead of learning the current language reach the goal of acquiring both faster in the end?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4043/800). Could you please edit your question to explain what type of information you can't find in the existing questions?

Comment: Immersion is supposed to be like being surrounded by a language for a given period of time (eight hours a day). So, yes, of course, it can be helpful.

Comment: Immersion can also be considered a method of teaching. For example, I've learned the local languages in three countries, and all fellow classmates were from various places and from various language backgrounds. Therefore, the teacher did not use a separate 'teaching language' (such as English), even in beginner classes. Instead, she used the local language (the target language) in a very simple and demonstrative fashion (e.g. using gestures, props, careful enunciation, etc.). To me, this is "immersion" as it applies to a teaching classroom.